# unable to start android virtual machine - genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I download genymotion with virtualbox latest version but whenever I try to run it first it showed black screen then later after following some answer from others in stackoverflow it began showing
[image]

and the virtualbox console shows this
[image]

i have tried several answers from stackoverflow and youtube but still nothing, I have even deleted an android emulator and downloaded another still nothing. Please what can I do to make it work

Answer (score 0):

For me,

Downgrading the VM Box from 6.1 to 6.0.24 solves the problem.

[Click here](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.24/VirtualBox-6.0.24-139119-Win.exe) to download VM Box 6.0.24